# No Row was updated. .... because it contains aggregate or DISTINCT clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im only trying to update a row (manually, with Management tools SQL Server 2008) and I have an error:

> No rows was updated. The data in row 1 was not committed. Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider. Error Message: Cannot update the view or function "viwTreeItems" because it contains aggregate or a DISTINCT clause.

Im trying to update a view alright, but I try to do it manually.. without any code or something, just changing a text (this text is a code inside a row.. but..I dont think thats the probelme...)

how can I update it ?

Comment: Show your query please.

Comment: SELECT     *
FROM         viwTreeItems
WHERE     TIID = 403

Comment: Add the view definition please and sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an issue due to the way the view was created. You are trying to modify the view rather than the original table with the data. This is possible as long as the view is not affected by a distinct, having or group by clause which it would appear you query is. I would suggest trying to find the table with the original data any modifying that one.

See the following [MSDN - Modifying Data Through a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) documentation for further information.